# Is there a way to SKIP the first execution of operators in unirx?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unirx

**What we want to do**

In the click event

- The first time, the value will be sent without a wait time.
- For the second action, the value is passed on one second after the
  event has settled down.

**Problems**

I was thinking that the following code could be used to achieve this if the Throttle process could be skipped only at the beginning.

```
GameObject button;
bool first = true;

button.onClick
      .AsObservable()
      .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMillseconds(1000))
      .Subscribe(() => {// action});
}
```

Comment: I'd advise against using _fancy tech_ such as _Reactive Extensions (Rx) and/or clones_ in a _**game**_ due to 1) noisy object generation 2) as with delegates risk of memory leaks if you don't unsubscribe (can be fatal if this traverses a new game level) 3) simpler alternatives available when making games.  Basically if you are using delegates you are at risk. https://www.amazon.com/Engine-Architecture-Third-Jason-Gregory/dp/1138035459

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 button.onClick.AsObservable().Skip(1)
```

Comment: I just have to add:
There are exact method in UniRx to observe button clicks:  
`var disposable = button.OnClickAsObservable().Skip(1)... `
this stream emits Unit elements. 
Therefore signature of subscribe should be: `Subscribe(_ => /*action*/);` 
or it's much pretier to pass method as a parameter: `Subscribe(SomeMethod);`